# use cdn library in vue js

Tags: vue.js, cdn

i have this code snippet and i must use this library for my vue js project:
i put this in my `index.html`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  !function(){function t(){var t=document.createElement("script");t.type="text/javascript",t.async=!0,localStorage.getItem("rayToken")?t.src="https://app.raychat.io/scripts/js/"+o+"?rid="+localStorage.getItem("rayToken")+"&href="+window.location.href:t.src="https://app.raychat.io/scripts/js/"+o;var e=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];e.parentNode.insertBefore(t,e)}var e=document,a=window,o="17a4bb2d-06c8-480d-ba58-045c86187534";"complete"==e.readyState?t():a.attachEvent?a.attachEvent("onload",t):a.addEventListener("load",t,!1)}();
</script>
```

the problem is i want to use a function of it inside of `created` hook in `App.vue` and i get undefined and when i use that function with delay it works.
how can i ensure that library is completely loaded and then use that function.

what is the solution??

App.vue:

```
          Raychat.setUser({
                email: this.$store.state.userInfo.email,
                name: this.$store.state.userInfo.name,
                phone: this.$store.state.userInfo.phone,
                updateOnce: true
           })
```

Comment: where is that script even from? Anyhow, you need to load this script before the Vue script, so that it is loaded when Vue is running.

Comment: where is the correct file to load that file . how can i fixed that

Comment: no clue what you're saying

Comment: Can you show how you're trying to access it from Vue and a link to your CDN package?

Comment: i have cdn library and i included it in head in public/index.html for global use. i want to use a method in library in created hook of App.vue? but i cant use that because the library not loaded yet and i get undefined so what is the solution?

Comment: App.vue code added to post

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can do it, and it really depends how much of the code snippet you want to edit. If you are at liberty to actually update/change the embed code, you can, instead of allowing to create a new `<script>` element, let it modify the `src` of a pre-existing empty `<script>` element to which you can attach an event listener to. I have remove the base64 number string for the `o` variable because it might be sensitive information:

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="raychat-script"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  !function(){function t(){var t=document.querySelector('#raychat-script');t.type="text/javascript",t.async=!0,localStorage.getItem("rayToken")?t.src="https://app.raychat.io/scripts/js/"+o+"?rid="+localStorage.getItem("rayToken")+"&href="+window.location.href:t.src="https://app.raychat.io/scripts/js/"+o;var e=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];}var e=document,a=window,o="...";"complete"==e.readyState?t():a.attachEvent?a.attachEvent("onload",t):a.addEventListener("load",t,!1)}();
</script>
```

Then, you can simply listen to the `load` event on `#raychat-script`, and invoke the logic that you need:

```
document.querySelector('#raychat-script').addEventListener('load', () => {
    // When the third party script is loaded
});
```

**Warning:** The major drawback of this method is that if another dev overwrites your embed code or that the company changes their strategy, it might not work.

---

If this is not an alternative, your only way is a passive solution, which involves creating some kind of polling method that simply checks if it is possible to access the `Raychat` variable:

```
let timer;
let attempts = 10;
const interval = 250;

function onRaychatLoadedCallback() {
    // Logic here
}

timer = window.setInterval(() => {
    if (attempts <= 0) {
        window.clearInterval(timer);
        console.warn(`Waited for ${attempts * interval / 1000}s, unable to detect if Raychat is loaded`);
        return;
    }

    if (Raychat && typeof Raychat === 'function') {
        window.clearInterval(timer);
        onRaychatLoadedCallback();
    }

    attempts--;
}, interval);
```